# Calculating time with datetime values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables where one has tasks, other has actions. In the task table I have tasks that ha ID, start date (when the task was created) and end date (when the task was closed). In the action table I have actions that were done in the task table so it has ID, task_ID, action_ID and time of the action.
I would like to calculate the time how long it took to close the task (end date - start date) but since there is a possibility to pause the task then I would like to exclude the paused time.
For example:

Action table:

```
ID      TASK_ID   ACTION_ID          TIME  
 1       2593         1              2020-03-25 07:05:48.000           
 2       2593         11             2020-03-25 11:05:48.000     
 3       2593         22             2020-03-25 20:05:48.000     
 4       2593         11             2020-03-26 07:05:48.000     
 5       2593         22             2020-03-27 07:04:31.000
 6       2593         2              2020-03-27 15:04:31.000
```

Task ID refers to the tasks table. Action ID 1 means task was opened, 11 means task was paused, 22 means pause was cancelled and 2 means task was completed/closed. 
So in the example the task was paused two times and I would like to calculate the time from the start (ID 1) to the end (ID 2) but not include the paused times (times between ID 11 and 22).

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't seem to understand what you like to do with these tables. Do you need to calculate the time difference between the records of same task_id that came multiple times?

Comment: I changed the times so it should be better to understand now. One task ID has multiple acitons (pause for example). I would like to calculate the time that it took to complete/close the task, so the time between action ID 1 and ID 2  but subtracting the pause time (between ID 11 and 22) from the total time. And if the task was paused multiple times then it should subtract all these pauses as it is shown in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the values are properly interleaved, you can use `lead()` to get the next value.  Then, you just want to add the times for actions 1 and 22.

```
select t.task_id,
       sum(datediff(second, time, next_time)) as total_time
from (select t.*, lead(time) over (partition by task_id order by time) as next_time
      from t
      where action_id in (1, 11, 22, 2)
     ) t
where action_id in (1, 22)
group by task_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=72abf21e573218e85388c891bbccf8d7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working. But how can I take the start and end dates from the task table and the pause times from the action table? Because I noticed there might be some tasks that have different action_id in the beginning or in the end but the task table has correct start and end dates. Thanks again.

Comment: Or take the start and end date from the action table but no matter what the their action_id is.

Comment: @Censoreb . . . According to your question, your action table has the starts, stops and pauses.  If you want to include two tables, I would recommend that you ask a *new* question, with sample data from *both* tables and a clear explanation of the logic.

Comment: It does not have to include two tables. It could take the first action_id as the start date and the last one as the end date, pause ID will remain the same.